# Remove #NV labels from bar chart

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following data:

```
     A 
1             Jan.    Feb.    Mar.    Apr.    Mai    Jun.    Jul.    Aug.   Sep.    Oct.    Nov.    Dez.
2   Revenue    500    400    =NV()     0      200    =NV()  =NV()    350      0     900    =NV()    400
3
4
```

Based on this data I created the following Excel barchart:

[image]

All this works fine so far.

---

However, as you an see in the barchart the `=NV()` values are dsiplayed as `#NV()`. 
Unfortunately, this is only happening using a barchart. If I switch to a line chart the `=NV()` is not displayed as label.

Therefore, I am wondering what I need to change either in my datas or in the label format to achieve the following:

a) `=NV()` values are not displayed as a label in the bar chart. 
b) `0` values are displayed as a label in the bar chart.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I use Excel 2007

Comment: I'm using `Excel 2019`, and these errors are natively neglected for me as labels. Maybe try one of the following: **1)** Use an `IFERROR(<formula>,"")` to show empty cells instead of `#NV`. Or **2)** Right click any of the labels and custom format them to `#,##0;-#,##0`. This is the standard that mine is set to =)

Comment: I am assuming #NV is the same as #NA.  In Excel 2013 the NA labels are displayed as well when labels are added to a 2D bar chart.  You can manually select the labels, then individually select a single label and delete it.  Using `IFERROR(NA(),"")` causes 0 to be displayed as a label instead of "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Office 2007:**

The only solution possible is the one already described in the comments of the question: 
Changing the `NV()` values to either `0` or `""` and then customize the `data labels` to:

```
[=0]"";#.##0
```

**Office 2010 or younger:**

The solution from the answer from *Forward Ed* can be used.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two step process which requires changing both your formula and changing your labels.  This solution is based on 2013 so you may need to adjust things to suit your version.

1)  As sugested by JvdV, Wrap your formula that is generating the values in the cells in an IFERROR function that gives "" as the result when there is an error. Similar to the following:

```
=IFERROR(NV(),"")
```

when properly applied to your cells, the cells should appear as blank cells

2)  Select the label series.  You will want to change the Format Data Labels.  By default in 2013, Value will be selected.  With this "Value" method "" is displayed as a 0.  Change the method from "Value" to "Value From Cells" and select range.  the selected range will be your displayed data.  When you do this, "" cells will display as blanks instead of 0.

Note in the following example, the IFERROR function was not used in L2 (Nov.) to demonstarte the difference.
[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not possible for Office 2007 because the option "Value From Cells" does not exist there: https://www.get-digital-help.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/custom-data-labels10.png